# Can there be more than 2 foreign key in laravel and how do i implement it?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Main category model as follow

```
class Maincategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function category(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

There is also a category model as follow

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function maincategory():BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Maincategory::class,'category_maincategory');
    }
}
```

And a subcategory

```
class Subcategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function category(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'subcategory_category');
    }
}
```

But i want the subcategory to be maincategory dependent. For example, consider main category of adult and kids with category of pants for both of them.Say, lets have subcategory of dungarees and formal pants for the pants's subcategory. I want formal pants for only adult and dungarees for only kids. It is easily accomplishable with creating different category with same name for both kids and adults. But I need the main category and category relationship to be many-to-many. Is there any way achieve this?